# Express / Nodejs route not able to grab the keys in an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, get

I am attempting to create a route in node / express that grabs data from a mongo db collection, and am running into a very frustrating issue. I have a collection named `nba_players_v2`, and have attempted to write the following route:

```
router.get('/shotcharts-v2/player/:player/season/:season', function(req, res) {
    let player_id = req.params.player;
    let season_id = req.params.season;

    console.log('playerid:', player_id, '   seasonid:', season_id);
    db.nba_players_v2.findOne({'_id': player_id}, function(err, player) {
        if (err) res.send(err);
        if (player) {
            console.log('player', player)
            console.log('typeof', typeof(player))
            console.log('keys', Object.keys(player))

            console.log('player firstname', player.firstName)
            let i = 0;
            for (var prop in player) {
                console.log(i, ':  ', prop)
            }
            ... 
        }
    }
}
```

I have removed the rest of the GET that is not important. When I launch node, and type in the route in the browser url on localhost, i receive the following output in terminal:

```
Express server is up and running on 8080 or process.env.PORT!
playerid: 9218    seasonid: 1617
player { _id: '9218',
  firstName: 'Stephen',
  lastName: 'Curry',
  birthDate: '1988-03-14',
  birthCity: 'Akron, OH',
  birthCountry: 'USA',
  highSchool: 'Charlotte Christian',
  college: 'Davidson College',
  officialImageSrc: 'https://ak-static.cms.nba.com/wp-content/uploads/headshots/nba/latest/260x190/201939.png',
  handednessShoots: 'R',
  FullName: 'Curry-Stephen' }
typeof object
keys [ '$__', 'isNew', 'errors', '_doc', '$init' ]
player firstname undefined

1 ': ' '$__'
2 ': ' 'isNew'
3 ': ' 'errors'
4 ': ' '_doc'
5 ': ' '$init'
6 ': ' 'db'
7 ': ' 'discriminators'
8 ': ' '__v'
9 ': ' 'id'
10 ': ' 'schema'
11 ': ' 'collection'
12 ': ' '$__save'
13 ': ' '$__validate'
14 ': ' '$__remove'
15 ': ' '$__init'
16 ': ' '$isMongooseModelPrototype'
17 ': ' '$__handleSave'
18 ': ' 'save'
19 ': ' '$__delta'
20 ': ' '$__version'
21 ': ' 'increment'
22 ': ' '$__where'
23 ': ' 'remove'
24 ': ' 'model'
25 ': ' 'on'
26 ': ' 'once'
27 ': ' 'emit'
28 ': ' 'listeners'
29 ': ' 'removeListener'
30 ': ' 'setMaxListeners'
31 ': ' 'removeAllListeners'
32 ': ' 'addListener'
33 ': ' '$__buildDoc'
34 ': ' 'toBSON'
35 ': ' 'init'
36 ': ' 'update'
37 ': ' '$set'
38 ': ' 'set'
39 ': ' '$__shouldModify'
40 ': ' '$__set'
41 ': ' 'getValue'
42 ': ' 'setValue'
43 ': ' 'get'
44 ': ' '$__path'
45 ': ' 'markModified'
46 ': ' 'unmarkModified'
47 ': ' '$ignore'
48 ': ' 'modifiedPaths'
49 ': ' 'isModified'
50 ': ' '$isDefault'
51 ': ' '$isDeleted'
52 ': ' 'isDirectModified'
53 ': ' 'isInit'
54 ': ' 'isSelected'
55 ': ' 'isDirectSelected'
56 ': ' 'validate'
57 ': ' 'validateSync'
58 ': ' 'invalidate'
59 ': ' '$markValid'
60 ': ' '$isValid'
61 ': ' '$__reset'
62 ': ' '$__dirty'
63 ': ' '$__setSchema'
64 ': ' '$__getArrayPathsToValidate'
65 ': ' '$__getAllSubdocs'
66 ': ' '$__handleReject'
67 ': ' '$toObject'
68 ': ' 'toObject'
69 ': ' 'toJSON'
70 ': ' 'inspect'
71 ': ' 'toString'
72 ': ' 'equals'
73 ': ' 'populate'
74 ': ' 'execPopulate'
75 ': ' 'populated'
76 ': ' 'depopulate'
77 ': ' '$__fullPath'
```

Clearly, the `findOne()` function is working, as the `console.log(player)` is printing out the player's object (in this case, some info on Steph Curry). However, when I attempt to `console.log()` the first name (which **is a key** in `player`), I receive undefined.

Its not particularly important that player.firstName is returning undefined, however there are other keys also returning undefined that I use in the rest of this `router.get` function that are also returning undefined.

Here is a screenshot of the relevant object (Steph's object) inside of the nba_players_v2 collection in my database (screenshot of Robo 3T):
[image]

I cannot get my app working without resolving this, so please please help. Let me know if i can share any other info (more `console.log()`) that will help with resolving this! I am new to web dev and managing the full stack on my own is tough, and bugs like this do not help!

Edit: do mongo DB _ids need to be unique only within a single collection, or must they be unique across the entire database? not likely the issue but just thinking...

Edit2: Should the _id key in the database be of type `ObjectId`, rather than of type `string`? I manually created the _id column (in R, before inserting to mongo db with mongolite), and it is clearly type string here.

Comment: Check it: `for (var prop in player) console.log(prop, ' : ', player[prop])`.

Comment: will edit above post with output - *it has been updated

Comment: im not even sure how to go about debugging this, which is part of the hassle. at a complete loss currently

Comment: i pasted the wrong info on the console.logs - it is a huge output, will edit below the post

Comment: the `player[prop]` output was massive, but i pasted the 77 props that printed - let me know if seeing `player[prop]` for any of the specific props would be helpful

Comment: Maybe player is `array`? Try `player[0]`

Comment: You don't have a player, you have a object "Collection" that have the information of the player. We don't know what dependency are you using to find the data, but in its documentation probably you have  the information of how get the information of the player. Probably, with the methods get or getValue, passing the key that you want to ask for.

Answer (score 2):

As you are using mongoose, [findOne](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne) returns to the callback a [Document](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#Document) object. If you want to have the firstName, you have to ask the document for it with [get](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-get).

```
player.get('firstName')
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but I can't add this as a comment because I've no reputation for that.

Are you sure that player is here an object? It seems to me like it is an unparser json string, so have no keys.

Comment: i will update the above with a `console.log` of the player type as well as the Object.keys

Answer (score 0):

GOT IT

[image]

In the models directory of my app, this is what most of my collection's Schemas look like. Which is okay for most collections, but NOT for the nba_players_v2 collections (or others used in the routes file).

Comment: No, the problem is not the schema, is a conceptual problem with the type of object that the callback is receiving. See my last answer.

Comment: Updating the schema resolved the issue i was having. For whatever reason, I needed to declare the keys / types that I was using in my routes.